# Error de contexto en fragmento

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, videoview

estoy insertando un video, lo cual se realiza de forma correcta, el problema es cuando quiero añadir los controles, al correr la app me aparece un error.

```
class BuscarFragment : FragmentoBase(R.layout.fragmento_buscar) {
    private lateinit var viewModel: BuscarViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BuscarViewModel::class.java)

        val mediaController = MediaController(this)  #me marca "this"
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
        var onlineUri = Uri.parse("https://video.mp4")
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.setVideoURI(onlineUri)
        videoView.requestFocus()
        videoView.start()
```

Este es el error.

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is DiscoverFragment but Context! was expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error es claro. El constructor `MediaController()` requiere un argumento de tipo Context y lo que le estas pasando es un Fragment.

Todo lo que necesitas hacer es reemplazar `MediaController(this)` por `MediaController(requireActivity())`

Bonus tip: La forma apropiada de obtener un ViewModel en kotlin es

```
private val viewModel: BuscarViewModel by viewModels()
```

bonus tip 2: En vez de repertir tantas veces "videoView" deberías usar una [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html)

```
videoView.run {
    setMediaController(mediaController)
    setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://video.mp4"))
    requestFocus()
    start()
}
```

Comment: Funciono todo, muchas gracias .

Comment: Como haría para que los botones aparezcan dentro del video, es decir por defecto se agregan en la parte inferior, quisiera que estén dentro del video como el reproductor de YouTube.

Comment: no lo sé, deberías crear una nueva pregunta a ver si alguien mas puede ayudarte

Comment: Podrías aceptar la respuesta? No debes dejar preguntas abiertas si ya encontraste solución